# How to get pm2 logs as json by exec function?

Tags: logging, pm2, request-promise

I'm enclosing my code so you can understand my intent, I want to get the last x lines of logs into res.data in my 'pm2exec' function.
I run the server by the command 'pm2 start...' in the terminal and then commit an API request.

```
private **getPm2Logs** = (request : Request , response :Response) =>  {
    // console.log(request.body[0]);
    console.log("pid : " + `${request.body.pid}`);
    const res : ASYNC_RESPONSE<any> = {success : false};
    //const requestBody : PM2_REQUEST = request.body[0]
    console.log(request.body);
    Pm2Manager.pm2exec(`logs --json --lines ${request.body.lines_count} --nostream `,`${request.body.pid}`)
        .then((data : ASYNC_RESPONSE<any>) => {
            res.success = data.success;
            console.log(res.success);
            res.data = data.data;    // TODO The logs are not transmitted properly
            console.log(res.data);
            response.send(res);
        })
        .catch((catch_data : ASYNC_RESPONSE<any>) => {
            res.data = catch_data.data;
            response.send(res);
        })

}


private pm2exec =  (pm2Command : string, pm2Item : string): Promise<ASYNC_RESPONSE<any>> => {
    return new Promise<ASYNC_RESPONSE<any>>((resolve, reject) => {
        let res: ASYNC_RESPONSE<any> = {success: false};
        exec(`pm2 ${pm2Command} ${pm2Item}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (stderr) {
                res.data = {};
                reject(res);
            } else {
                res.success = true;
                res.data = JSON.parse(stdout);
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: did you find any solution?